# In Typescript, how can I make a KeyBy generic type? Create an object keyed by a specific column from an array of objects

Tags: typescript

I have an array of objects type, and I'd like to convert it to an object keyed by a property in each of the objects. Conceptually similar to Lodash's KeyBy, but in types.

```
type Arr = [
    {slug: 'test-1', value: string},
    {slug: 'test-2', value: string},
    {slug: 'test-3', value: string},
]

type KeyBy<A extends object[], S extends keyof A[number]> = {
    //1. how do I get numeric indexes of A for iteration and mapping?
    //2. how do I convert those numeric indexes to the literal types of the matching property?
}

type Keyed = KeyBy<Arr, 'slug'>

/* desired result: 
{
    'test-1': {slug: 'test-1', value: string},
    'test-2': {slug: 'test-2', value: string},
    'test-3': {slug: 'test-3', value: string},
}
*/
```

I think the generic constraints I've put on the KeyBy type are appropriate, but it's not required to fit that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [this is definitely possible](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTnKBeKBtAsAKCjqBvAZwBsBXAcwC4oByYCA4AWgEZqAaKANwENSIqGcAJYA7MhyEATKswC+bLLnzFyVWvSYAmdl14l+UQaPFQpVTfMW5CpSjToNGAZh08+A4MLETpUJ5cwAXSwsUEgoAGkIEAhJACEQAB4YDgBlKAgADzoRSQIoAAU4AHtIOFAokAA+ZFgM7Ihc-Pg4biTRADMIRAAVGoB+SOjYhIBJETo4EV5EnrSaqhEITm6AbhDMMOhKkZBxyemiWbT6nLzCkrKK6JqUdKyz-IBraOKOqB6oQbwrVAjTEQfVCpQJQbj5ACiDSaiQiHCKpW612qgSoUMexygACUIABjYpwSSJVIcCJVKpYWRQRbLNYbLZQdGNPKzZgcHqaW4fZinZn5DlfbnUqBLFZwdaYULgbbDSS1HbxJItDjUFRkagUzbSoYxSSaeWyhLJBAqqQaqXhBVOA26o3KmhufTmyWYAD0ACooJJ6EI4LEoH6CCQiMAqFgfthcOpHKwqDZVPYNCxXHoDEYxAElNGtNQ42q1A4cxxHWnPMZM1HC85c8pbAWky5i6mPF4yAFZFh3a6gA):

```js
type KeyedBy<A, S extends PropertyKey> = A extends Array<infer T>
  ? KeyedByInternal<T, S>
  : never;

type KeyedByInternal<T, S extends PropertyKey> = S extends keyof T ? {
  [K in T[S] as Extends<K, PropertyKey>]: Extends<T, Record<S, K>>
} : never;

type Extends<T1, T2> = T1 extends T2 ? T1 : never;
```

This gets you all the behavior you want, both for selectors that produce literal types as *well* as for selectors that produce "universe" types (e. g. `string` or `number`):

```js
// Tests
type Arr = [
    {slug: 'test-1', value: string, id: 1},
    {slug: 'test-2', value: string, id: 2},
    {slug: 'test-3', value: string, id: 3},
]

type Keyed = KeyedBy<Arr, 'slug'>
/* 
{
    "test-3": {
        slug: 'test-3';
        value: string;
        id: 3;
    };
    "test-1": {
        slug: 'test-1';
        value: string;
        id: 1;
    };
    "test-2": {
        slug: 'test-2';
        value: string;
        id: 2;
    };
}
*/


type Keyed2 = KeyedBy<Arr, 'id'>
/* 
{
    3: {
        slug: 'test-3';
        value: string;
        id: 3;
    };
    1: {
        slug: 'test-1';
        value: string;
        id: 1;
    };
    2: {
        slug: 'test-2';
        value: string;
        id: 2;
    };
}
*/


// IT WORKS FOR NON-LITERAL TYPES TOO!
type Keyed3 = KeyedBy<Arr, 'value'>
/*
{
    [x: string]: {
        slug: 'test-1';
        value: string;
        id: 1;
    } | {
        slug: 'test-2';
        value: string;
        id: 2;
    } | {
        slug: 'test-3';
        value: string;
        id: 3;
    };
}
*/
```

The real insight is that we can filter the right hand side of our union type with `Record<S, K>` (where `S` is our literal type representing a `Selector` into the object type and `K` is the current key we're computing in our [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html)) in order to focus the value to the branch(es) of the union type we're dealing with that match our selector.

Comment: Wow, okay. So, first you use `infer` to create a union type of the elements of the array, then you index on a union of the values of matching keys, (filtering out any values that aren't valid property keys), then assign K to the original union type, but filtered to only members who extend a record made up of only K and the value at hand...? That is humbling, ha. Very nice, and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After spending a bit more time on this, I have a working solution to solving this using numeric indexes, although not quite as robust as @Sean's solution, in that it doesn't support universal types, but it is perhaps easier to follow, at least for me.

```
/* helpers */
type IndecesOfArr<Arr extends any[]> = Exclude<Partial<Arr>['length'], Arr['length'] | undefined>;
type Extends<T1, T2> = T1 extends T2 ? T1 : never;

type Arr = [
    {slug: 'test-1', value: string},
    {slug: 'test-1', value: string, test: number}, //matching keys would be unioned
    {slug: 'test-2', value: string},
    {slug: 'test-3', value: string},
    {slug: ['non-indexable'], value: string}, //should be excluded from result
]

type KeyBy<A extends object[], S extends keyof A[number]> = {
    [I in IndecesOfArr<A> as Extends<A[I][S], PropertyKey>]: A[I]
}

type Keyed = KeyBy<Arr, 'slug'>

/* expected result: 
{
    'test-1': {slug: 'test-1', value: string} 
        | { slug: 'test-1', value: string, test: number},
    'test-2': {slug: 'test-2', value: string},
    'test-3': {slug: 'test-3', value: string},
}
*/
```

The `IndecesOfArr` type works because of typescript's treatment of `Arr['length']`. When given a literal array, it actually tells you the literal length instead of just `number`. If you wrap the `Arr` in `Partial<Arr>`, it tell you all the possible lengths (0 - length) as a union. We're excluding the full length number to get a zero based union of all the lengths.

In the mapping index, we're leveraging these indeces, and casting the index to a key with the value of that index's `S` property literal value. Then we assign that key to value of that index in the original array.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2#code/PQKgBAFgpgNgDlATgZzCYAoALgTwWASQDsATKAYymQHkAzAQUUQB5HEwoAPLKU1AQyI4A2gF0AfGAC8YAKKdyMAK5lmABX6IsAS34xWTccIDkMXgHMsEY6IA0YNibNFL10WAA%20YJaSi1tRFAk4gDc2HhQcty8JMjMACoAjPbxAEySMkkc0XxgaWAA-HmJYABcYIEAbkhh4fhs0mDCGGCtYADeyMrm5cY8yFgAtInG9pV6SlDlA4gB5gC%20ti1tnd29-UMjYxNTYDNz9hvlREoAtgBGSIvLratKPWB9VEOpo2Djyrv7LtdtHV33dbPQYAZjeH0m0ywsx%20Sz%20dweJiIAHsiIMAmROPxzmYbNtPlCYQsMKIMHVIgBpKA4ABCOFY2R4uWR5wAVhQsGJ7ABlRkxVAAa2pyNoDmEJwuSAkjXaNyaBDAAUIvkoNAYTFYkn4qHkTNirGEBFEwm5djAakQyIQWhwVJw4lE5XohtJ8zJuHwdqCjTtdIMiHsxgB5mM4jJoGyCHIPBIYEQVCUMCw5Qwsr%20TwGw2M5QRQMzW3eO0Jc3mYDlfy87T2a0eGyz%20Mhe2hBzARwqZ0uiF%20bQzL2z-xrvcGrwbX2bsLlQ7BOeDeaGYNHxYnbvQQA)